# How do I remove initial indents on numbered lists?

Tags: microsoft-word, indentation

In Word 2007 I want all numbers in a numbered list to be down the LH margin in line with the paragraphs.

When a numbered list is selected, the numbers 1,2,3 are indented by a default 0.63cm.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> will shift this indent back to the left margin.

How do I permanently remove that initial indent and save that change to the normal template so that all new documents have zero indent on a newly inserted numbered list?

(Same issue in Word 2010)

Comment: See also useful answers at  https://superuser.com/questions/965463/ms-word-edit-space-after-numbers-in-titles-list

Answer (score 2):

Find the file, normal.dotx on your computer and right click to open (not new).  This will open the template Word uses when creating new documents.  Insert a numbered list.  Right click and go to adjust list indents.  Select the indent spacing you like.

**Delete the numbered list** and save the changes to normal.dotx.  My normal document is stored in this location. C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates

[image][image]

Comment: Once I delete the numbered list in the Normal Template in Word 2007, and insert a new list, again the same indenting problem comes.

Comment: I could find normal.dotm in the C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates folder, but not the normal.dotx