# Remove Tab After number in auto-numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Word automatically (and invisibly) inserts a tab after the number(s) in all auto-numbered styles. How can these be removed/replaced?

Comment: Why do you want to remove those tabs? They are there so the paragraphs are indented correctly ...

Comment: In some cases, users want a certain number of spaces after the number.  For example, a Standard Naval Letter (as defined in SECNAV Instruction M5216.5 calls for the paragraph number, a period, and then two spaces, rather than a tab with a preset distance regardless of the number.  Or, the user may want to enter spaces manually.  I'm curious as well, but I stuck to the question.

Comment: I recommend "Confounded"'s answer here as the easiest way   https://superuser.com/questions/965463/ms-word-edit-space-after-numbers-in-titles-list

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft Word numbered lists are complex, arcane, frustrating, and easily corrupted.  I'm only answering your specific question in this response but there is quite a bit to learn about numbered lists in Word.

Note: relevant image links will be at paragraph start in following paragraphs.  You can use control + click to open these images in new windows or tabs.

See image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKz72.png).  Select the Multilevel List drop down arrow (at top red arrow) then select "Define New List Style...."  The Define New List Style dialog box will appear.  In the Name: field, enter a name like "Just numbers no tabs."

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDFEy.png) Modify your new multi-level list style.  Select the multilevel list drop down arrow.  The Modify Style box should appear.  Hover your mouse and you should see the multi-level list style name pop up.  You can select your list in either "Current List" or in "List Styles." Right-click on the list name and select "Modify."

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CLhR.png) The Modify Style" dialog box should appear.  Select "Format" then "Numbering...."

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mtgh.png) The "Modify Multilevel List" dialog box will appear.  In the "Modify Multilevel List" dialog box, Select "More>>."  Note that you're currently on the top level (Level 1) of your list and that each level has to be modified, so you'll be repeating this process for each list level you'll use.

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SR7C.png)  In the expanded "Modify Multilevel List" dialog box, find the "Follow number with:" field.

[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZIZ4.png)  In the "Follow number with:" selection box, select either "Space" or "Nothing."  Select "Ok", then select either the next level (Level 2) and repeat this process or select "Ok" again to close all dialog boxes.

[7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evl0I.png)  You will note that your list style now contains no tab character after the numbered sidehead.

Like I said, numbered lists in Word are a huge pain in the ass.  Post back with any comments on this question or post a new question if you're trying to understand some other element of numbered lists.

Comment: The "multilevel list" aspect of this is important; I had to switch to that to see it. Unfortunately that messed up my Heading styles, but fortunately the effects were all visible in the Styles pane.

Comment: Sadly, the dialog boxes I get in Word 2013 do not match what you show in your excellent instructions here.    I also do not get the "tab after" option as described here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-you-change-the-tab-after-value-for-the/a1cb3f67-3890-4937-8b4b-dc5bc5f043fe   .

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you:

1. Left Click on the number of the numbering
2. Right Click - Option Window opens
3. Left Click on adjust list indent
4. Change "Text after" to nothing