# Chapter headings are misaligned in word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I have finsihed my phd thesis and ready to submit the corrections but I am having an issue with the chapter headings. The "Chapter x" is slightly misaligned with the text. It looks like it has a space after the number as if it wants more words but i cant remove that space, and I think that is throwing it off. Any help would be appreciated (see screenshots). The pages have a wider margin for binding purposes.

[chapter 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObpnM.png)

[chapter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN5MK.png)

less noticeable when chapter names are longer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byz9j.png)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Have you check the paragraph parameters of Chapter 6 heading and compared it to the others? Verify that the space after is not different.

Comment: Sorry I am not great with word, how would i do that? It may be worth noting that the tesxt undernath which says "discussion" is just plain text, not a heading. I didnt know how to make discussion appear underneath Chapter 6 without it being plain text

Comment: I figured out how to make it so the "discussion" was part of the chapter heading but on the line below but it is still misaligned with "Chapter 6" above it

Comment: Could you post a small example document to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @harrymc here is an example of what the issue is, if you see the headings arent aligned to each other [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/6z6ccq5xrppar85/example%20file.docx?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given in below link. You basically need to adjust / set up a new multilevel list.
[remove-tab-after-number-in-auto-numbering](https://superuser.com/questions/1414113/remove-tab-after-number-in-auto-numbering)